# The way to declare variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem in vba.

Here is the **Code:**

```
Sub GetData()
If IsNumeric(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value) Then
flag = False
i = 0
id = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
        flag = True
        For j = 2 To 3
            UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
        Next j
    End If

    i = i + 1

Loop

If flag = False Then
    For j = 2 To 3
        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
    Next j
End If

Else
ClearForm
End If
End Sub
```

My problem is with first If statement. It only works when i declare variables like:

```
Dim id As Integer
Dim i As Integer
```

or

```
Dim i, id As Integer
```

But it **doesn't** work when i declare them like:

```
Dim id, i As Integer
```

It acts like when condition is false.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

When you Dim more than one variable in a line separated by a comma

e.g.

```
Dim i, id as Integer
```

..only the first variable (`i`)  will be dimensioned correctly. The second variable (`id`) will be a variant.

Comment: actually other way around... `Dim i, id as Integer` will dim `i` as `Variant` and `id` as `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx (especially the section "Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement") for a good discussion of how variables are declared. In your case, only `id` will have an explicit type (`Integer`). Variable `i` will be of the default type, `Variant`.

Note that this differs from VB.NET, where both variables would have `Integer` type.